# Spectral measure is sigma finite

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

The spectral theorem states that for a self-adjoint linear operator $A$ with $\left\|A\right\|=1$ on a Hilbert space, there is a measure space $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ so that $A$ is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator on $L^2(I,d\mu)$ where $I:=[-1,1]$. If $H$ is separable, then $\mu$ can be taken to be  a finite measure.

Now my question is: If $H$ is not separable, can we always take $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: you should probably say "on a Hilbert space $H$"

Answer (score 1):

If every real $x\in[0,1]$ is an eigenvalue, then the $\mu$ cannot be sigma finite.

Comment: For instance, let $H = \ell^2([0,1])$, i.e. $L^2$ of $[0,1]$ equipped with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra and counting measure.  Then define $(Af)(x) = x f(x)$.